# What is the name of this houseplant?

Tags: identification, houseplants

This plant is houseplant.  A friend gave another friend of mine this plant without knowing it's name.  I want to have the correct name to help my friend because she is looking for the name of this plant and she didn't find it.

[image: photo of unknown plant]

Comment: Looks like some kind of orchid, did it ever had flowers?

Comment: Thank benn for your answer .Yes it has small white flowers look a bit like the orchid flowers but not as beautiful as orchid flowers

Comment: It might be wise to add a picture of the flowers too, it will increase the chance that someone knows what plant this is here.

Comment: The presentation of plantlets makes it look like a species of Clorophytum (spider plant) to me. There are many species in this genus. The vegetative forms are quite varied. https://www.pacificbulbsociety.org/pbswiki/index.php/Chlorophytum

Answer (score 1):

It is an orchid.  Even you say it looks like a orchid flower.  You state it's not as showy as an orchid, but there are actually 20,000 different species of orchids in the world; not all of them are showy.  Those that are showy and easy to grow are the ones we are most familiar with.

If you want to know the exact species, either wait until it flowers and add a picture to this post, or I would suggest going to either Houzz or Garden.org.  They both have orchid forums.  You could even email a national orchid society.   Post this picture and one of the flower if you have it.  One of these forums maybe able to give you the exact species.  Once you have learned the answer, please come back here and answer your own question.